# table view control like folder in IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hey I'm new to iOS and I am searching for a custom table view like in folder design as i have mentioned in my attached screenshot. I have tried a lot in Google for such custom table, but i didn't find any good sample. If user will tap on this table folder then it will display their 4 or 5 options. Can you please suggest me any sample or link related to my problem.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @iPatelThanks for your quick response, i have checked in cocoa controls before..but there was not any menu sample like folder.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=&q=menu

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel use this control

Answer (score 1):

This type of interface was popularised by Evernote (this should help your google search). Here is an  open source implementation:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/klnoteviewcontroller

[image]

Comment: Thanks@ColinE, here i don't have to display all options initially. It should come after tapping only.